Iterating with Selenium without being blocked
Following from the previous question...
I have a list of URLs I need to scrape with Selenium, but it always blocks me after getting the results from the first one.
This is what I'm doing:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--headless') # ensure GUI is off
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

expres = pd.DataFrame()

    d2 = ['http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-cerimonia-de-inauguracao-do-hospital-notre-dame-barretos-sp',
 'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-a-visita-a-25a-edicao-da-feira-internacional-de-tecnologia-agricola-em-acao-agrishow',
 'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/brinde-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-no-almoco-oferecido-em-homenagem-ao-senhor-desire-delano-bouterse-presidente-da-republica-do-suriname',
 'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/declaracao-a-imprensa-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-apos-assinatura-de-atos',
 'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-a-solenidade-de-abertura-oficial-da-84a-exposicao-internacional-de-gado-zebu-expozebu-2018']

for j in d2:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(j)
    cont = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content-core']"))).text
    print(cont)

On the first iteration, it gets the desired content.
On the second, I get this message:
TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:192:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:510:5
dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:136:16

What am I doing wrong? Should I give it more time?

I'm not sure how we're supposed to help when you haven't provide the relevant HTML or better yet, a link to the page.

Done! Same group of links as before.

Why are you making a new WebDriver instance with each iteration? Especially without closing the last one. You're basically expecting to have 5 chrome instances open by the end. Try moving the initialization out of the loop.

So that's what I was getting wrong!

So the first issue I noticed is that you are creating a new instance of Chrome and maximizing it inside the loop. I'm assuming this is not intentional. If you pull those out and define your WebDriverWait once outside the loop, everything worked for me. I did change the XPath to an ID since you were only looking for the ID. It makes it simpler, easier to read, etc.
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

d2 = ['http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-cerimonia-de-inauguracao-do-hospital-notre-dame-barretos-sp',
'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-a-visita-a-25a-edicao-da-feira-internacional-de-tecnologia-agricola-em-acao-agrishow',
'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/brinde-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-no-almoco-oferecido-em-homenagem-ao-senhor-desire-delano-bouterse-presidente-da-republica-do-suriname',
'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/declaracao-a-imprensa-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-apos-assinatura-de-atos',
 'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-a-solenidade-de-abertura-oficial-da-84a-exposicao-internacional-de-gado-zebu-expozebu-2018']

for j in d2:
    driver.get(j)
    cont = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "content-core"))).text
    print(cont)

This prints the text you were looking for with no exceptions.

Just for fun I took the code above, put it into a data driven test using pytest, and set it up to run in parallel. Now each URL is launched in its own browser, speeding up the scraping process significantly. With these 5 URLs, each URL is launched in its own browser meaning in the time it takes to scrape one, you can scrape all 5. Anyway... feel free to use this or not. The above code works just fine.
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

@pytest.mark.parametrize("url",
        ['http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-cerimonia-de-inauguracao-do-hospital-notre-dame-barretos-sp',
        'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-a-visita-a-25a-edicao-da-feira-internacional-de-tecnologia-agricola-em-acao-agrishow',
        'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/brinde-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-no-almoco-oferecido-em-homenagem-ao-senhor-desire-delano-bouterse-presidente-da-republica-do-suriname',
        'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/declaracao-a-imprensa-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-apos-assinatura-de-atos',
        'http://www.biblioteca.presidencia.gov.br/presidencia/ex-presidentes/michel-temer/discursos-do-presidente-da-republica/discurso-do-presidente-da-republica-michel-temer-durante-a-solenidade-de-abertura-oficial-da-84a-exposicao-internacional-de-gado-zebu-expozebu-2018'])
def test(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(url)
    cont = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "content-core"))).text
    print(cont)

To run this, you will need to install pytest and pytest-xdist. See the docs for more info on pytest.

I had't yet tested. Just did it now. Thanks, it worked perfectly!
So, my error was that I was opening a new instance for each URL and that's why they blocked me out?

"They" weren't blocking you, you were getting a timeout exception. My assumption is that it was because each loop you were creating a new instance of chromedriver which loses your connection with previous instances causing issues.
